# Pegar mensagens enviadas e recebidas do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de mensagens pessoais e preciso listar as mensagens que eu recebi e as mensagens que eu enviei, só que estou tendo dificuldades, pois o código que fiz só consegue pegar todas que eu enviei ou todas que eu recebi e nunca as duas. O código que estou usando

```
<?php    
$query = mysql_query("SELECT pr.id_perfil, pr.id_perfil_enviou, pr.recado, pe.nome as NomeEnviou, prm.nome as NomeRecebeu FROM perfil_recados AS pr INNER JOIN perfil AS pe ON pe.id = pr.id_perfil_enviou INNER JOIN perfil AS prm ON prm.id=pr.id_perfil WHERE (pr.id_perfil='961' AND pr.id_perfil_enviou = '15') OR (pr.id_perfil='15' AND pr.id_perfil_enviou = '961')");

while($exe = mysql_fetch_array($query)){                    
   echo 'De: '.$exe['NomeEnviou'].' para '.$exe['NomeRecebeu'];    
}
?>
```

Comment: Viu, então você não deveria ter duas SELECT's?? Porque nem sempre você vai enviar, e ela vai ter uma resposta. Ou seja em apenas um SELECT pra mim acho que não vai dar...

Comment: Considere usar a cláusula UNION do SQL. http://blog.tiagopassos.com/2010/07/20/realizando-duas-ou-mais-consultas-com-union-e-union-all-no-mysql/

Comment: Obrigado @Tony o **UNION** me ajudou no que eu precisava!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considere usar a cláusula **UNION** do SQL.

> No MySQL a palavra-chave UNION é usada para combinar o resultado de
>   múltiplos comandos SELECT em um único resultado.

Exemplo:

exemplo:

```
(SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cidade = 1 LIMIT 3)
UNION (SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cidade = 5 LIMIT 3)
UNION (SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id_cidade = 8 LIMIT 3)
```

Referência:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Nessa caso acho UNION ALL mais interessante. Não creio que os dados irão se repetir e a performance do UNION ALL é superior pois ele não precisa checar por duplicadas. [Detalhes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Answer (score 0):

E se você fizer assim

```
SELECT pr.id_perfil, 
       pr.id_perfil_enviou, 
       pr.recado, 
       pe.nome AS NomeEnviou, 
       prm.nome AS NomeRecebeu
FROM perfil_recados AS pr 
INNER JOIN perfil AS pe ON pe.id = pr.id_perfil_enviou 
INNER JOIN perfil AS prm ON prm.id = pr.id_perfil 
WHERE pr.id_perfil IN (15, 961) 
   OR pr.id_perfil_enviou = (15, 961);
```